# TypeScript compiler evaluates let differently than const

Tags: typescript

Following page 64 in Boris Cherny's *Programming TypeScript*, consider a JavaScript function like this:

```
function warnUser(warning) {
  if (warnUser.wasCalled) {
    return
  }
  warnUser.wasCalled = true
  alert(warning)
}
warnUser.wasCalled = false
```

which will warn a user no more than once.
We want to use TypeScript to type its full signature:

```
type WarnUser = {
  (warning: string): void
  wasCalled: boolean
}
```

Then we can implement it in TypeScript like so:

```
const warnUser: WarnUser = (warning) => {
  if (warnUser.wasCalled) {
    return
  }
  warnUser.wasCalled = true
  alert(warning)
}
```

but try the same thing with `let` instead of `const` and you get an error:

```
let warnUser: WarnUser = (warning) => {
  if (warnUser.wasCalled) {
    return
  }
  warnUser.wasCalled = true
  alert(warning)
}
```

> Property 'wasCalled' is missing in type '(warning: string) => void' but required in type 'WarnUser'.ts(2741)>

Why is `let` problematic but `const` fine?

Comment: The value you use to initialize `warnUser` does not match its declared type. TypeScript reports the mismatch in both cases.

Comment: This is interesting. At first I assumed you made a typo, but can confirm this behaviour.`Property 'wasCalled' is missing in type '(warning: string) => void' but required in type 'WarnUser'.(2741)
input.ts(3, 3): 'wasCalled' is declared here.`

Comment: And changing the let tot a const makes the problem go away

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function property assignments are only allowed on function declarations and `const` variables initialized with a function/arrow expression. This is a rule ingrained in the compiler, as described in the [TS 3.1 changelog](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions).

> Why is let problematic but const fine?

Probably because of safety reasons. `let` creates a mutable binding, so you potentially could have reassigned another value before and aren't setting a property on the function expression anymore.

TS also forbids double function declarations, therefore both rules can be statically analyzed  and enforced in a predictable way.