# Property missing in type but it is required

Tags: typescript

Just for practicing I have this code:

```
type WarnUser = {
    wasCalled: boolean
    (warning: string): void
}

let warnUser: WarnUser = (warning: string) => {
    if(warnUser.wasCalled) {
        return
    }
    warnUser.wasCalled = true;
    alert(warning)
}

warnUser.wasCalled = false;
```

But the error I am getting is this:

```
 Property 'wasCalled' is missing in type '(warning: string) => void' but required in type 'WarnUser'.
```

I am not sure how to fix this error now.  Can you help?

Comment: You can change `let` to `const` and it will work (more infos [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887033/typescript-compiler-evaluates-let-differently-than-const/59888038))

Answer (score 0):

Changing `let` to `const` should fix this problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).