# late assignment and lazy type checking in typescript intersected types

Tags: typescript

Recently I saw a code like this (in order to have some kind of namespacing):

```
function f0() {
  return "string";
}

function f1() {
  return 4;
}

type F0 = typeof f0;
type F1 = typeof f1;

const first: F0 & { f1: F1 } = function() {
  return "sample";
};

first.f1 = f1;
```

the interesting point is that if we remove the `first.f1 = f1` line, the typescript compiler gives an error for `f1` variable and says

> Type '() => string' is not assignable to type '(() => string) & { f1: () => number; }'.

It seems that type checking happens it two steps and it is kind of a lazy type checking! 
My question is that how is this possible?

It is more interesting when we cannot do this with `object` based types. For instance in the following code, it type checking system raises error as expected

```
const second: { n1: number } & { n2: number } = { n1: 10 };
second.n2 = 8;
```

Can anyone elaborate what's the reason for this behaviour? (You can see and run the above code here too : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-9chzq)

Comment: TypeScript is quite pragmatic (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness), in as much as things don't necessarily have to make consistent sense, but rather things seem to be added on the basis of them being useful. Having a function with properties is somewhat tricky to define in one expression (though can be done), in early versions of TypeScript what you wrote would get a complaint. Functions are just a special case, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions for notes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript compiler evaluates let differently than const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887033/typescript-compiler-evaluates-let-differently-than-const)

Comment: @ford04the question is not about the difference between the 'let' and 'const', it is mostly about how a lazy type checking can be done.